# How to add Group Count on Reporting Pages (rdl)

Tags: rdl

Here is my question...I have a RDL report that has four groupings.  I am using Count to show how many records are within each group.  I am wanting to display one of the Grouping Counts above so you don't have to drill down to the next level.

So let me see if I can explain.
On Group 1 Row 1, I have a column with "Count (5)"
On Group 2 Row 1, I have a column with "Count (3)"
On Group 2 Row 2, I have a column with "Count (2)"

So Group 2 Row 1 and 2 add up to Group 1 Row 1.  I am wanting to break out Group 1 Row 1 with the information shown in Group 2.